# Obter os valores em pixel de um determinado ponto na tela

Tags: php, javascript, css

Olá, sou novo aqui portanto se houver algum erro de formatação, desculpe-me!

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução WEB e nela preciso carregar uma imagem no browser e selecionar 4 pontos dentro dessa imagem e obter os seus valores dos pixels que foram selecionados nesses 4 pontos.
Minha duvida é como fazer tais seleções e capturar seus valores em pixel? É possível fazer isso com alguma linguagem WEB (PHP, JavaScript, CSS, etc)?

Já efetuei varias pesquisas no Google e o mais próximo que encontrei foi a utilização da biblioteca GD do PHP, mas que também não atendeu para o que eu preciso.

Aguardo resposta e agradeço pela colaboração!

Comment: Aconselho a utilizar o [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_canvas.asp) do HTML5

Comment: ref. [Pixel Manipulation](http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel)

Comment: Voce quer fazer isso ao lado do servidor?

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Obrigado pelas resposta. lazyFox irei estudar sobre o canvas. @TheProHands a marcação dos pixel seria do lado cliente mesmo. Obrigado!